# How do I find the derivative of arcsin(z)

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

We know that: $$\arcsin(z)=-i\operatorname{Ln}(iz+\sqrt{1-z^2})$$ So after applying the chain rule I end up with the following expression which I can't think of ways to simplify:
$$-i\frac{(i-\frac{z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}})}{\sqrt{1-z^2}+iz}$$
Can you help me understand what do I have to do here to simplify?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: $\arcsin z=\arctan(z/\sqrt{1-z^2}).$

Comment: IF it only says "find the derivative" then you have an answer.  Of course, that answer may be simplified to $1/\sqrt{1-z^2}$, but the question didn't say "in simplest form" or something, did it?

Comment: @GEdgar It is not a question from any textbook. I just want to derive it for myself, however I just can not think of ways to simplify this more.

Comment: $-i(i-\frac{z}{(1-z^2)^{1/2}})=1+i\frac{z}{(1-z^2)^{1/2}}=\frac{(1-z^2)^{1/2}+iz}{(1-z^2)^{1/2}}$ so the simplification is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do two things to start simplifying this expression. First, we can take the $-i$ term from out front and multiply it across the numerator. Second, we can take a factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$ out of the numerator so that we don't have nested fractions. When we do that, we notice that we get:

$$\begin{eqnarray} \frac{d}{dz} \arcsin z & = & -i \frac{i - \frac{z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}}{iz + \sqrt{1-z^2}} \\
& = & \frac{-i^2 + \frac{iz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}}{iz + \sqrt{1-z^2}} \\
& = & \frac{1 + \frac{iz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}}{iz + \sqrt{1-z^2}} \\
& = & \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2} + iz}{iz + \sqrt{1-z^2}} \\
& = & \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}
\end{eqnarray}$$

which is the known derivative of arcsin on the domain $[-1, 1]$. Now in the complex numbers this is glossing over a lot of issues with multiply-valued expressions.

There is another way to derive this that I think is a bit simpler, by using implicit differentiation (and for the sake of consistency I will even use the complex definition of the sine function rather than rely on its known derivative):

$$\begin{eqnarray} w & = & \arcsin z \\
\sin w & = & z \\
\frac{e^{iw} - e^{-iw}}{2i} & = & z \\
\frac{i e^{iw} \frac{dw}{dz} + i e^{-iw} \frac{dw}{dz}}{2i} & = & 1 & \mbox{differentiating with respect to } z \\
\frac{dw}{dz} \frac{e^{iw} + e^{-iw}}{2} & = & 1 \\
\left( \frac{dw}{dz} \right)^2 \frac{e^{2iw} + 2 + e^{-2iw}}{4} & = & 1 \\
\left( \frac{dw}{dz} \right)^2 \left(\frac{e^{2iw} - 2 + e^{-2iw}}{4} + 1 \right) & = & 1 \\
\left( \frac{dw}{dz} \right)^2 \left(1 - \left(\frac{e^{iw} - e^{-iw}}{2i}\right)^2 \right) & = & 1 \\
\left( \frac{dw}{dz} \right)^2 (1 - z^2) & = & 1 \\
\frac{dw}{dz} & = & \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - z^2}}
\end{eqnarray}$$

Again, there's a bit of hand-waving in the choice of branch for the square root, but otherwise everything is fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Using Mathematica

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"];
```

Starting with the relation

```
rel1 = f[z] == ArcSin[z]

(* f[z] == ArcSin[z] *)
```

Take the `Sin` of both sides

```
rel2 = ApplySides[Sin, rel1]

(* Sin[f[z]] == z *)
```

Take the derivative of both sides

```
rel3 = ApplySides[D[#, z] &, rel2]

(* Cos[f[z]] f'[z] == 1 *)
```

Replace `f[z]` with `ArcSin[z]` (i.e., `rel1`)

```
rel4 = rel3 /. Rule @@ rel1

(* Sqrt[1 - z^2] f'[z] == 1 *)
```

Since,

```
Cos[ArcSin[z]]

(* Sqrt[1 - z^2] *)
```

Solving `rel4` for `f'[z]` gives the derivative of `ArcSin[z]`

```
rel5 = Equal @@ Solve[rel4, f'[z]][[1, 1]]

(* f'[z] == 1/Sqrt[1 - z^2] *)
```

Verifying,

```
D[ArcSin[z], z]

(* 1/Sqrt[1 - z^2] *)
```